# Double double questionmarks in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have found such kind of code:

```
const dealType = currentDealType ?? originalDealType ?? '';
```

What `?? ??` what does mean the syntax?

Comment: It's not a special operator, it's the same operator applied twice. The same way as in `1 + 2 + 3`, it's `+` used twice not `+ ... +`

Comment: It is [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) used twice :-)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It's the nullish coalescing operator that has been proposed for ecmascript and has been implemented in Typescript. You can read more [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26578) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

The gist of it is that

```
const dealType = currentDealType ?? originalDealType;
```

is equivalent to:

```
const dealType = currentDealType !== null && currentDealType !== void 0 ? currentDealType : originalDealType;
```

Or in words: if `currentDealType`  is `null` or `undefined` use `originalDealType` otherwise use `currentDealType`

Comment: The example in the docs helped me understand the difference between this and `||`. This operator is only applied to nulls and undefineds instead of all falsy values, so `0 || 5 -> 5` whereas `0 ?? 5 -> 0`

Answer (score 3):

To the question of the double usage of the nullish coalescing operator, `??`, the code mentioned is simply chaining usage of it. You can use the nullish coalescing operator in succession with multiple variables. The first non-nullish variable in the chain will be used.

```js
const w = null;
const x = undefined;
const y = 'foo';
const z = 'bar';

const word = w ?? x ?? y ?? z;

console.log(word);
```

Answer (score 3):

`??` is the Nullish coalescing operator.

`a ?? b` evaluates to:

- `a` if `a` is neither `null` nor `undefined`
- `b` otherwise

When chaining `??` such as `a ?? b ?? c`, you will get the first value from the left that is neither `null` nor `undefined`.

So in the example

`const dealType = currentDealType ?? originalDealType ?? '';`

`dealType` will be assigned to:

- `currentDealType` if `currentDealType` is neither `null` nor `undefined`
- otherwise `originalDealType`  if `originalDealType`  is neither `null` nor `undefined`
- otherwise `''`

Note that `a ?? b` is different from `a || b` since

- `??` only checks for `undefined` and `null`
- `||` checks for any falsy value which includes `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `NaN` and `''` among others.