# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?" executing Next.JS scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, null-coalescing-operator

I'm learning Next.JS by following the [freecodecamp tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nextjs-tutorial/), and running `npm run dev` gives the following error output:

```
showAll: args["--show-all"] ?? false,
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

I'm running npm version 8.19.2 and node version 18.12.1, which should support null coalescing.

Grateful for any ideas.

I tried updating my node and npm versions, and ensuring they support null coalescing. According to [some previous answers on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74707066/nextjs-unexpected-token) that aught to have done it.

Comment: are you using typescript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426269/double-double-questionmarks-in-typescript

Comment: @windmaomao yes, create-next-app sets up a typescript application